# Android: Vulkan layers have stopped functioning on device

Tags: android, c++, vulkan

I am developing an app using Vulkan, using a Google Pixel. I was successfully calling `vkCreateInstance`, and rendering. However, now when I call `vkCreateInstance`, I get `VK_ERROR_LAYER_NOT_PRESENT`. I am not requesting any layers, and I am only attempting to load `VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME`, `VK_KHR_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME`, `VK_KHR_ANDROID_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME` extensions (code is unchanged from what was working).

If I download other Vulkan apps, they report the same issue (for example, the [Hardware CapsViewer for Vulkan](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.saschawillems.vulkancapsviewer&hl=en)). Also, when loading apps, I also get the following messages:

```
02-02 09:14:34.603 28290 28308 D vulkan  : searching for layers in '/data/app/de.saschawillems.vulkancapsviewer-1/lib/arm'
02-02 09:14:34.603 28290 28308 D vulkan  : searching for layers in '/system/fake-libs'
02-02 09:14:34.603 28290 28308 D vulkan  : searching for layers in '/data/app/de.saschawillems.vulkancapsviewer-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a'
```

At some point, I wanted to get a frame capture to get a better data about a graphics problem I was having on the Google Pixel. I loaded up both the Nvidia Tegra Profiler, and the Snapdragon Profiler. I suspect that one of these tools has changed something on my device to cause it to stop functioning.

Do the required Android Vulkan layers exist in the system outside libvulkan.so (which exists and loads)?

When I run `adb shell getprop`, these two match 'vulkan':

```
[debug.vulkan.layer.1]: [sdp]
[debug.vulkan.profiler]: [1]
```

It is possible that these (or perhaps some properties) could cause it to stop loading layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the properties. Apparently they are added by the Snapdragon Profiler, which did not shutdown correctly. If I open it again, and close it, it sets these properties on shutdown, and everything works again.

```
[debug.vulkan.layer.1]: []
[debug.vulkan.profiler]: [0]
```

Comment: As a side note, since the Snapdragon Profiler sets these each time at startup, and they cause Vulkan apps not to run, I'm not sure how you're supposed to use it to profile Vulkan apps :).

Comment: You can just run `adb shell setprop debug.vulkan.layers '""'` instead of shutting down device everytime fyi